# How to create textfield/securefield with show password funcionality but without dismissing keyboard?

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios14

I'm trying to create password field using textfield/securefield like that:

```
    @ViewBuilder
    private func secureField() -> some View {
        if showPassword {
            TextField(
                "Password",
                text: $password)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .autocapitalization(.none)
        } else {
            SecureField("Password",
                        text: $password)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .autocapitalization(.none)
        }
    }
```

and the button:

```
    var showPasswordButton: some View {
        Button {
            showPassword.toggle()
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: showPassword ? "eye" : "eye.slash")
        }
    }
```

but every time when I'm toggling show password, the keyboard dismisses. Do you guys know any solution here? It have support iOS14.

Comment: This can be achieved since iOS 15, with the `.focused()` modifier.

Comment: "It have support iOS14."

Comment: You may have to make two different password fields and display either variant depending upon the OS with an `#ifAvailable`. The key to doing what you are asking is `.focused(). You could also use a `UIViewRepresentable` and use UIKit.